# Notice: undefined offset: 10, even with matching number of array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm pretty much trying to separate all the returned values from preg_match_all, there are 3 values.

We get everything inside the strong tags, numbers into one array, text into another, and everything after the strong tags goes into the third, but I keep getting this error that I don't want to ignore.

This is the notice: `Notice: Undefined offset: 10 on line 49`, and it's `$saveExtra = $matches[2][$key];` all the way at the bottom of the code.

```
$html = "<strong>1 1/4 lb.</strong> any type of fish
<strong>3 tsp.</strong> tarragon
<strong>3 tsp.</strong> tomato sauce
<strong>1 tbsp.</strong> coconut oil
<strong>Pepper and Salt</strong>, it's optional
<strong>2 tbsp.</strong> oil
<strong>1/4 cup</strong> cream
<strong>1/4 tsp.</strong> tarragon
<strong>1/4 tsp.</strong> tomato sauce
<strong>Salt and Pepper</strong>, it's optional too
";
$variations = array('lb', 'tsp', 'tbsp', 'cup');

$setInfo = [];
$arr_amount = [];
$extra_arr = [];
$arr_units = [];

if(preg_match_all("/<(?:strong|b)>(.*)(?:<\/(?:strong|b)>)(.*)/", $html, $matches)) {

    foreach($matches[1] as $amounts){
        preg_match_all("/^(?:[\p{Pd}.\/\s-]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟])+/um", $amounts, $amount);
        preg_match_all('/[a-zA-Z :]+/m', $amounts, $unit);

        foreach($amount[0] as $amount_arr){
            $arr_amount[] = $amount_arr;
        }

        foreach($unit[0] as $units_rr){
            $arr_units[] = trim(strtolower($units_rr));
        }

        $unit_id = array();
        foreach($arr_units as $key => $unit_arr){
            foreach($variations as $unit_var){
                if(strtolower(trim($unit_arr)) == $unit_var){
                    $unit_id[] = $unit_var;
                }
            }

            if(str_word_count($unit_arr) >= 2){
                $arr_amount[$key] = '';
                $unit_id[$key] = '';


                $saveExtra =  $matches[2][$key];
                $matches[2][$key] = $unit_arr . $saveExtra;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If we `print_r($arr_amount, $unit_id, $matches[2])`, we get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 1/4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 1
    [5] => 
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 1/4
    [8] => 1/4
    [9] => 1/4
    [10] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => lb
    [1] => tsp
    [2] => tsp
    [3] => tbsp
    [5] => 
    [6] => tbsp
    [7] => cup
    [8] => tsp
    [9] => tsp
    [10] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] =>  any type of fish
    [1] =>  tarragon
    [2] =>  tomato sauce
    [3] =>  coconut oil
    [4] => , it's optional
    [5] => pepper and saltpepper and saltpepper and saltpepper and saltpepper and saltpepper and salt oil
    [6] =>  cream
    [7] =>  tarragon
    [8] =>  tomato sauce
    [9] => , it's optional too
    [10] => salt and pepper
)
```

I've been at this for the past 2 days without being able to figure out why I keep getting undefined offset when the `$key` is matching to that current iteration.

I've put the code up on eval, https://eval.in/883856

Comment: Whenever I play with `preg_match_all` I tend to use the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag to group them by matching set rather than the default `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`

Comment: You are finding more units in `$arr_units` (11 items) than pattern matches in  `$matches[2]` (10 items)

Comment: I see, just noticed there are no [4] keys in the first two items.

Comment: @Scuzzy, after taking a careful look at what you said, I noticed that the $arr_units was returning empty values, hence the 11 items instead of 10. I fixed the regex and now it's working correctly. I appreciate it, without your insight I wouldn't have figured this out.

Comment: I also didn't know about PREG_SET_ORDER, it will come in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third item in `$match` (*i.e* `$match[2]`) is an array with 10 items. PHP arrays have zero-based index.

From my observation, `$key` at some point equals `10`.

Add a guard clause against this like so before accessing `$key` in `$match[2]`:

```
if($key >= count($matches[2])) continue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.